# VS Code : search and replace in multiple files with a regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Under my app i ve several .list files , each file contains several variables declarations:

**File 1 :**

```
myVarString=abc
myVarUrl=http://aaaaa.test.mywebsite.com:8080
...
```

**File 2 :**

```
myVarString=abc
myVarUrl=http://bbbbbbbbbbb.test.mywebsite.com:8080
...
```

**File n :**

```
myVarString=abc
myVarUrl=http://nnnnnnnnnnn.test.mywebsite.com:8080
...
```

Using VSCode , i want to dynamically search out someting like this

**http://(*).test.mywebsite.com:8080**

and replace the value of **(*)** with a given string

**Suggesstions ?**

Comment: It is done in the opposite way: you capture what you need to keep,  and just match what you want to remove: `(http://)\S*(\.test\.mywebsite\.com:8080)` -> `$1some_new_value$2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is done in the opposite way: you [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) what you need to keep, and just match what you want to remove.

**Find**: `(http://)\S*(\.test\.mywebsite\.com:8080)`
**Replace**: `$1some_new_value$2`

To match literal dots, you should escape them.

To match any chars other than whitespace, you may use `\S*`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xAkHo6/2) and a [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(http%3A%2F%2F)%5CS*(%5C.test%5C.mywebsite%5C.com%3A8080)):

[image]